# NodeJS Worker Threads - message sending before function finished?

Tags: node.js, event-handling, worker-thread

I am using a pool of workers to complete some CPU intensive tasks in Node.

However, I have a problem in my code below. When a task is first run, everything goes as expected, the pool is created, then is called which sends a message to a thread that runs the task successfully and responds with a message. However, on a second call, it seems to run the callback function of the worker (via the parentPort.postMessage) before the work in the threaded file is done. This seems to be an issue with using promises here? I see the "This run was complete in X ms" log before the "done" message shows. Why is this happening? Is something wrong with my workerPool class?

Am I not able to use any async/promise logic within the worker?

The version of Node I'm using is 14.

I followed largely the example set in this doc: https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#class-asyncresource

workerPool.js:

```
const { AsyncResource } = require("async_hooks");
const { EventEmitter } = require("events");
const path = require("path");
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");

const kTaskInfo = Symbol("kTaskInfo");
const kWorkerFreedEvent = Symbol("kWorkerFreedEvent");

const { MONGODB_URI } = process.env;

class WorkerPoolTaskInfo extends AsyncResource {
  constructor(callback) {
    super("WorkerPoolTaskInfo");
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  done(err, result) {
    console.log("<<<<<<<<<<<");
    this.runInAsyncScope(this.callback, null, err, result);
    this.emitDestroy(); // TaskInfos are used only once.
  }
}

class WorkerPool extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(numThreads, workerFile) {
    super();
    this.numThreads = numThreads;
    this.workerFile = workerFile;
    this.workers = [];
    this.freeWorkers = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) this.addNewWorker();
  }

  addNewWorker() {
    const worker = new Worker(path.resolve(__dirname, this.workerFile), {
      workerData: { MONGODB_URI },
    });
    worker.on("message", (result) => {
      // In case of success: Call the callback that was passed to `runTest`,
      // remove the `TaskInfo` associated with the Worker, and mark it as free
      // again.
      worker[kTaskInfo].done(null, result);
      worker[kTaskInfo] = null;
      this.freeWorkers.push(worker);
      this.emit(kWorkerFreedEvent);
    });
    worker.on("error", (err) => {
      // In case of an uncaught exception: Call the callback that was passed to
      // `runTest` with the error.
      if (worker[kTaskInfo]) worker[kTaskInfo].done(err, null);
      else this.emit("error", err);
      // Remove the worker from the list and start a new Worker to replace the
      // current one.
      this.workers.splice(this.workers.indexOf(worker), 1);
      this.addNewWorker();
    });
    this.workers.push(worker);
    this.freeWorkers.push(worker);
    this.emit(kWorkerFreedEvent);
  }

  runTest(data, callback) {
    if (this.freeWorkers.length === 0) {
      // No free threads, wait until a worker thread becomes free.
      console.log("No free threads. Process queued.");
      this.once(kWorkerFreedEvent, () => this.runTest(data, callback));
      return;
    }

    const worker = this.freeWorkers.pop();
    worker[kTaskInfo] = new WorkerPoolTaskInfo(callback);
    worker.postMessage(data);
  }

  close() {
    for (const worker of this.workers) worker.terminate();
  }
}

module.exports = WorkerPool;
```

The index.js file where workers are called:

```
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    threadPool.runTest(
      { ...some data },
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Bad error from test:", err);
          reject(err)
        }

        const endTime = new Date();

        // this callback is fired before the message is supposed to be posted...

        console.log("Run Test Complete");
        console.log(`This run took ${endTime - startTime} ms`);

        resolve(true);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

The code that actually runs in the worker:

```
const { parentPort, threadId, workerData } = require("worker_threads");

parentPort.on("message", async (data) => {

  // await func1(...)

  // await func2(...)
  
  console.log("Done");

  parentPort.postMessage('Done stuff);

});
```

Comment: Why do you do this: `if (err) return console.error("Bad error from test:", err);` instead of rejecting the promise.  Your code does not report errors back to the caller through the promise.

Comment: Where the code  that actually runs in the worker?  Your description makes it sounds like you're sending `parentPort.postMessage('Done stuff);` before all the other code in the worker is done, but you don't show us the code in the worker that is probably creating the problem.

Comment: This code is really hard to follow.  You should get rid of your mixing of callbacks and promises here and just use promises.  You're passing callbacks multiple levels deep and it makes things really hard to follow.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm largely following the example set in these docs: https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#class-asyncresource
Sorry I didn't write it particularly well at first, the last block of code is what's run in the worker. Listening for messages before posting back results, but that postmessage seems to run before the code above it is executed.

Comment: Yeah well, then show us the code that is likely causing the problem.  What you show as `func1()` and `func2()` are functions that probably are not written properly.  That's probably where the problem is so we can't help you unless you show us that code.